# Android Studio - Gradle Sync Failed - ToolingRegistryProvider

Tags: android, gradle

Hi looking for some help as I am not having much luck trying to develop in AndroidStudio.  A couple of months ago I had android studio running and I updated it. Ever since I have been getting the follow error when ever I build any project.

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: com.android.build.gradle.internal.ToolingRegistryProvider.
```

When I clean the project I see the following message.

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/gradle/internal/ToolingRegistryProvider
```

I have tried the following to resolve the issue.

1. Uninstall and try again.
2. Unistall and manually remove left behind files.
3. Download latest gradle version and manually use those files when building.

If anyone could point me in hte right direct I would be very grateful is this is driving me up the wall.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754587/noclassdeffounderror-com-android-build-gradle-internal-toolingregistryprovider

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/gradle/internal/ToolingRegistryProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754587/noclassdeffounderror-com-android-build-gradle-internal-toolingregistryprovider)

Answer (score 0):

According to this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776313/3356270) you have to remove Gradle module cache like so:

```
rm -r ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2
```

Comment: On a Linux machine and inside Android Studio, you click `Terminal` on the "Tool Buttons" bar (in my case located at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks, I am using a windows machine :-( , going to  manually find location and delete and see what happens

Comment: No joy with solution

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions here while uninstalling and reinstalling Android studio and my problem was resolved.

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

Thanks